# Unwanted borders in tables

Tags: css, html-table

I have a borderless table, I want alternate rows to have a background color. I set CSS background-color on the tr element, it gives all the cells in the row the color I want but there is a thin white line between each of them. How can I get rid of this?

Following is very simple demo of the phenomenon. Note the unwanted thin white line between the cells on row 2. Adding border, border-spacing, or border-collapse properties seems to make no difference. I've tried this on Firefox and Chrome, both behave the same.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width:135px">
      <col style="width:135px">
      <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color:#87CEEB">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Comment: Please add the table code and related css to your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this blog post about how to get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this code to your css file.

```
table, th, td {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have some code posted in your question or people trying to assist may not be able to give you a precise answer. Without any HTML and css to go from, I can only speculate what you may need.

The border-collapse CSS property sets whether cells inside a  have shared or separate borders.

```css
border-collapse: collapse;
```

or

```css
/* When cells are separated (border-collapse: separate;), the distance between 
cells is defined by the border-spacing property.*/

border-spacing: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Apparently the solution is to put border-collapse:collapse on the table element, not on the tr or td. Hope I haven't put you all to too much trouble!